# Como fazer múltiplos valores em um único option e recupera-los

Tags: javascript, value, option

Eu quero saber como posso fazer uma lista com um separador específico "|" e definir mais de um valor em `select-option` e recuperar em *JavaScript* com um `split("|")` para uma variável, algo como:

```
<select id="teste">

  <option value="valor1|valor2" >Opcao 1 </option>

</select>
```

recuperando JavaScript

```
var A = valor1

var B = valor2

extrair = function(){

var txt = document.getElementById("teste");

var valores = txt.options[txt.selectedIndex].value;

alert(valores)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre abaixo a resposta a sua pergunta.

```js
var opcao = document.getElementById('teste'); //busca o select

function extrair(separador){ //funcao extrair que retorna um array com os valores
  if(opcao.selectedIndex!=0) return opcao.value.split(separador); //separa os valores pelo [separador]
}

opcao.onchange=function(){ //evento de mudanca de estado
    var valores = extrair('|'); //inicializa a funca extrair para obter os resultados
    console.log(valores); //lista o array
    console.log("Valor 1: "+valores[0]); //lista valor 1
    console.log("Valor 2: "+valores[1]); //list valor 2
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Como fazer múltiplos valores em um único option e recupera-los</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <select id="teste">
  <option>Selecione uma opcao</option>
  <option value="valor1|valor2" >Opcao 1</option>
 </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Caso nao queira utilizar a propriedade `onchange` do elemento pode sempre adicionar um eventListener `opcao.addEventListener(EVENTO, FUNCAO)`.

```
opcao.addEventListener('change', function(){
    var valores = extrair('|'); //inicializa a funca extrair para obter os resultados
    console.log(valores); //lista o array
    console.log("Valor 1 no event listener: "+valores[0]); //lista valor 1
    console.log("Valor 2 no event listener: "+valores[1]); //list valor 2
})
```

Comment: Procure explicar o código que usa, e o porque de o fazer assim. (nota: o `onchange` atribuído dessa forma vai fazer rewrite à propriedade)

Comment: @MoshMage como assim (em relação ao rewrite) ? Poderia me explicar o que seria isso e como, nesse caso, escrever o código certo ?

Comment: @MoshMage usei  o  **onchange** so para passar o exemplo. **Mais** por definicao o evento **onchange** nao tem accao.

Comment: @GonsaloSousa o downvote não é pelo uso de on-change, é porque isto embora responda à pergunta - não explica ao user *o porque* de resolver a pergunta *nem tão pouco o que este estava a fazer de mal*

Comment: @MoshMage e onde voce explicou ao user oque ele estava a fazer de mal? Leia de novo a pergunta, o **onchange** foi apenas um extra. O autor da pergunta demonstra conhecimento basico, e apenas pede como recuperar os valores. O seu downvote foi mal colocado...

Comment: @GonsaloSousa Não tem a ver *com este user* mas sim *com o próximo*, embora sim o meu dv tenha sido precipitado (mas por isso é que estes demoram até ficarem salvos).

Comment: @GonsaloSousa Esta legal, serviu-me de inspiração agora deixarei o meu voto. Att+

Answer (score 1):

Abaixo esta o código para capturar os múltiplos valores em um único `option` que será utilizado em nosso "teste" está bem comentado, dispensando maiores detalhes.

```js
extrair = function() {

var texto = document.getElementById("teste"); // aponta para select alvo

var valores = texto.options[texto.selectedIndex].value; // armazena os valores na variável

var array = valores.split("|"); // cria-se o array

   alert("var A = "+array[0]); // exibir valor 1

   alert("var B = "+array[1]); // exibir valor 2

}
```

```html
<select id="teste" onchange="extrair(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  
 <option>Selecione uma opcao</option>
 <option value="valor1|valor2" > Opcao 1 </option>

</select>
```